# How do I make swig aware of c++ namespaces?

Tags: python, c++, swig

Hi I am trying to create a python binding for a little stack machine I wrote and chose to try swig for it.

The problem is that the generated code wont compile because some classes are unknown. The reasons for that is, that my classes are all inside a namespace.

The class I want to create a wrapper for looks like this:

```
#ifndef STACK_MACHINE_H
#define STACK_MACHINE_H

#include <stack.h>
#include <operand.h>
#include <instruction.h>
#include <program.h>

namespace stackmachine
{
    class stack_machine
    {
    public:
        stack_machine() = default;
        void run();
        void load (instruction* op);
        vrml_variable* get_stack_top();

    private:
        stack m_stack;
        program m_code;
        
    };
}
#endif
```

The first problem is the `load` method. The `instruction` class is defined in one of the headers, and is also inside the `stackmachine` namespace:

```
#ifndef INSTRUCTION_H
#define INSTRUCTION_H

#include <stack.h>

namespace stackmachine
{
    class instruction
    {
    public:
        virtual ~instruction() = 0;
        virtual void execute(stack& current_stack) = 0;
    };

    inline instruction::~instruction()
    {
        
    }
}

#endif
```

Here is a snipped of generated code:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_stack_machine_load(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  stackmachine::stack_machine *arg1 = (stackmachine::stack_machine *) 0 ; // namespace used => OK!
  instruction *arg2 = (instruction *) 0 ; //namespace ignored => error
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  void *argp2 = 0 ;
```

Now the interface definition is as simple as possible and probably the place where I need to make changes, but so far I have not found a hint on what to do:

```
%module stackmachine
%{
#include <stack_machine.h>
%}

%include <stack_machine.h>
```

Adding the instruction.h to the includes does not change anything.

It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I did try using "includeall" and it changed the problem, now the instruction class is known but standard c++ headers like vector and string wont be found. And I don't really want to include all available classes in the wrapper.

Comment: What version of swig are you using?

Comment: I use version 4.0.2 and the code generation is part of a cmake script

Comment: You added `%include "instruction.h"` to the .i file?  You'll probably need `stack.h`, `program.h` and `operand.h` as well.  Anything in the public interface.

Comment: "Anything in the public interface" was the solution. Thank you. If you would post it, i could mark it as the answer for any later readers.

Comment: It would be a good learning experience to make a binding for this simple class using the Python C API directly.  Also using Pybind11 or one of the other C++ Python binding libraries.  SWIG is all right if you need bindings for several languages I guess, but when you're doing something simple like this for just Python, it sure gets ugly quick.

Comment: I have several other projects where I need bindings between languages, which is why I wanted to try swig. This project seemed fitting to try it, because it's relatively simple. And I only use python because I wanted to see if it is a fast way to build a basic linux desktop application around my stack machine (with wxPython or PyQt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any class/function/global in the public interface may need a `%include` to generated wrapper code.  SWIG does not recursively include without `-includeall` but that's not desirable as that would try to wrap system headers.

Order matters as well.  SWIG needs to generate wrapper code for `instruction` before `stack_machine` since it is used by `stack_machine`.

```c
%module stackmachine
%{
#include <stack_machine.h>
%}

// as needed...
%include <stack.h>
%include <operand.h>
%include <instruction.h>
%include <program.h>
%include <stack_machine.h>
```